# Swift Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called

Tags: ios, swift

I am calling this function below in the simulator to simulate background fetch.

Then I get this warning in the log:

> Swift Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

I have seen other Stack Iverflow answers say I just need to add  `completionhandler()`. I've tried this and it says I need to add a parameter and that's where I am lost.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler:@escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    //check if user online
    let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(uid)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
            if document.exists {
                guard let dictionary = document.data() else { return }
                guard let onlineOfflineStatus = dictionary["Online Offline Status"] as? String else { return }

                // if online create value to set offline an alert
                if onlineOfflineStatus == "Online" {
                    print("user is Online and inactive, will set value to trigger notification asking if they would like to go offline")
                    db.collection("sendGoOffline").document(uid).setData(["OfflineAlert" : 1200], completion: { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("there was an error", error)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        if let error = error {
            print("failed to fetch user", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `completionHandler` with the appropriate parameter value as shown I the documentation.

Comment: Call the completion handler after processing the data

Comment: can anyone give me code samples of what i need to do i still have no clue even after reading the documentation

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: @ElTomato I have the same issue right now. Can you give the sample call? I don't know what parameter to put in to `completionHandler()`, since I don't have a `UIBackgroundFetchResult`.

Answer (score 7):

The warning is telling you to add this method:

```
completionHandler(argument)
```

where the `argument` is one of the following:

```
UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData
UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData
UIBackgroundFetchResult.failed
```

The purpose is to tell the system that you are done.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler:@escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // do backgound data fetch

    // process it

    // finished
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

Read more here:

- [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application)
- [old but good article](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/)
- [UIBackgroundFetchResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibackgroundfetchresult)

Remote notification related articles

- [How to handle remote notification with background mode enabled](https://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/)
- [Multiple scenarios with Push Notification in iOS](https://medium.com/fantageek/push-notification-in-ios-46d979e5f7ec)
- [application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)